# Django: Efficient way of obtaining a number of items based on foreign key

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

Here's an example:

Models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=120 blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.Foreignkey(Category)
```

This is what i made previously:

```
products = [Product.objects.filter(category_id=i.id)[:6] for i in Category.objects.all()]
```

How can i efficiently obtain a list containing 6 products per category without using 'for'?

Comment: `products = [Product.objects.filter(category_id=i)[:6] for i in Category.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)]`
 not sure, how to do without for but this is how i ll do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has a really nice way of making an array from a subquery. So if you use Postgres this will work for you.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

class Array(Subquery):
    template = 'ARRAY(%(subquery)s)'

product_sub = Product.objects.filter(category=OuterRef('pk'))

products = Category.objects.annotate(
    product_list=Array(product_sub.values('name')[:6])
).values_list('product_list', flat=True)
```

This way is more efficient:
Let's compare with your version

Your version: 1 query for categories + count of categories multiplied by 1 query for products. One for loop.

My version: 1 query.

Comment: and after that i still need to make a for in 'products' in order to get the list from each category

Comment: glad to help you